# How to find which hostname:pid opened the file on NFS?

Tags: solaris, nfs

is there a way to find which hostname:pid opened the file on NFS?

We have 2k boxes which use same NFS mount and there is a process
running somewhere which opened a file. It's impossible to login
everywhere and furthermore some of them are solaris boxes lacking
lsof.

Is there a way to ask NFS server which box has opened particular
file?

Answer (score -1):

No.  The file is open on the local box.  The local box only knows the process name/pid

Are you trying to unshare?  Dismount the disk that is shared?  umount -f /mountpoint
wil dismount the disk.

Comment: > No. The file is open on the local box.
Does this mean NFS server knows nothing about opened file?

> Are you trying to unshare? Dismount the disk that is shared? 
I can't do that. This is a production system.